# SwiftもしくはObjective-Cのキューの状態をSidekiqの管理画面のように可視化するツールはありますか？

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c, マルチスレッド

## Sidekiqの管理画面

sidekiqには、管理画面があります。
どのキューにどれだけジョブが溜まっているなど、まだ処理がされていないジョブを確認できたりします。

参考: https://www.mikeperham.com/2014/03/28/sidekiq-3-0/

## キューを可視化する方法はあるか

例えば、前回の質問

[DispatchQueue.main.async の実行される順番について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57823/dispatchqueue-main-async-%e3%81%ae%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e9%a0%86%e7%95%aa%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

では、メインの`キュー`とその`タスク`が可視化できれば、`タスク`の増え方と減り方によって何が起こっているのか把握できたと思います。

また、複雑なアプリであれば、複数のキューに思いがけないタスクが登録されている場合があります。

こういったときに役に立つキューの状態を可視化できるツールはありますか？